# Orange Canvas: pythonw.exe has stopped working crashing

Tags: python, orange

I have a random problem with Orange. I developed a widget and I have a button who opens a new window for some settings. The program works fine, but, at a some point, totally randomly, pythonw.exe stops working. It's only when I use the window for settings. The problem happens totally randomly, but more often when I open the window. I tried to make my window with OWW.OWBaseWidget, OWW.OWWidget and OWW.QDialog. I tried too with pythonw.exe and python.exe. I did the same thing that Set Colors of the widget Data Table in Data. But this one crashed too after a moment.

So where is the problem? Orange? Python? Anything else? I have no error message.

I have Windows 8.1, python 2.7 and Orange 2.7.8.

Comment: I'm afraid there is not much we can do without at least an extensive crash dump.

Comment: But I am on Windows 8.1 and I have not an extensive crash dump. How can I have it?

Comment: Apparently there is a way, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21720765/464709). Of course, once you have the dump you will still have to extract the useful information from it so you can post that information here. Chances are you will understand the problem in the process.

Answer (score 0):

Is this helpful? I am on a french version of windows:

Description

Chemin d’accès de l’application défaillante :   C:\Python27\pythonw.exe

Signature du problème
Nom d’événement du problème :   APPCRASH

Nom de l’application:   pythonw.exe

Version de l’application:   0.0.0.0

Horodatage de l’application:    4df4b9cc

Nom du module par défaut:   QtCore4.dll

Version du module par défaut:   4.7.0.0

Horodateur du module par défaut:    4cbe7403

Code de l’exception:    c0000005

Décalage de l’exception:    000c7f03

Version du système: 6.3.9600.2.0.0.768.101

Identificateur de paramètres régionaux: 4108

Information supplémentaire n° 1:    5861

Information supplémentaire n° 2:    5861822e1919d7c014bbb064c64908b2

Information supplémentaire n° 3:    84a0

Information supplémentaire n° 4:    84a09ea102a12ee665c500221db8c9d6

Informations complémentaires sur le problème
ID de compartiment :    3a2b179ef07f0847bf9f72213260bff5 (-1296411611)